# Under what representation do the Christoffel symbols transform?

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, covariance

I often read the statement, that the Christoffel symbols aren't tensors. But then, under which representation do they transform?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Christoffel symbols do not transform under **any** representation. The reason for this is that they do not transform linearly, which puts them out of the game altogether. The transformation law is

$$ \tilde \Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu\kappa} = {\partial \tilde x^\mu \over \partial x^\alpha} \left [ \Gamma^\alpha_{\beta \gamma}{\partial x^\beta \over \partial \tilde x^\nu}{\partial x^\gamma \over \partial \tilde x^\kappa} + {\partial ^2 x^\alpha \over \partial \tilde x^\nu \partial \tilde x^\kappa} \right ]$$

(for a proof see e.g. [this math.se question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248267/christoffel-symbol-transformation-law)). As you can see, its possible for $\tilde \Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu\kappa}$ to be nonzero even if $\Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu\kappa}$ vanishes identically, which is fatal for linearity.

The reason this is important is that a [representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation) is a mapping from the symmetry group $G$ of spacetime into the group of linear transformations on some given vector space $V$. Thus: no linearity, no representation.

Answer (score 12):

First, they do *not* transform in an actual "representation" in the sense of a linear representation of the group of coordinate transformation since their behaviour under a coordinate transformations $x\mapsto y(x)$ is given as
$$ {\Gamma^\alpha}_{\beta\gamma} \overset{y(x)}\mapsto \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial y^\beta}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial y^\gamma}{\Gamma^\sigma}_{\mu\nu}\frac{\partial y^\alpha}{\partial x^\sigma} + \frac{\partial y^\alpha}{\partial x^\sigma}\frac{\partial^2 y^\sigma}{\partial x^\beta \partial x^\gamma}\tag{1}$$

Nevertheless, their transformation is *not* "random", since they have that form to make the covariant derivative transform as a proper tensor. They transform as an object in the [jet bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_bundle) of the [frame bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_bundle) of the spacetime $\mathcal{M}$. Now, what does this mean?

A coordinate transformation $y(x)$ determines at every point $p\in\mathcal{M}$ an invertible linear map
$$ y'_p : T_p\mathcal{M}\to T_p\mathcal{M}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\mapsto\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial y^\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu} $$
i.e. $y'$ is a diffeomorphism $T\mathcal{M}\to T\mathcal{M}$ of the tangent bundle that's compatible with the projection onto the base.

To the tangent bundle, there is the *frame bundle* $F\mathcal{M}$ of all ordered bases of $T_p\mathcal{M}$ at every point. "Ordered base" means you just take the $n$ basis vectors and write them into an $n\times n$-matrix. Since it is a base, this matrix is invertible - the space that the frame bundle associates to every point is that of $\mathrm{GL}(n)$, and it is hence a $\mathrm{GL}(n)$-[principal bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_bundle).

The "Christoffel symbols" are now just the components of a principal connection on that bundle, where a "connection form" is better known to physicists as a *gauge field*, this one taking values in $\mathfrak{gl}(n)$, i.e. the Christoffel form is a 1-form $\Gamma : T\mathcal{M}\to\mathfrak{gl}(n)$. Its gauge transformations are given by $y_\text{gauge} : \mathcal{M}\to\mathrm{GL}(n), p \mapsto y'_p = \frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial y^\mu}\rvert_p$ for a coordinate transformation $y$, and like every gauge field, it transforms as
$$ y_\text{gauge} \Gamma y_\text{gauge}^{-1} + y_\text{gauge}\mathrm{d}y_\text{gauge}^{-1}$$
The coordinate expression is $(1)$ is reobtained from this by writing $\Gamma = {\Gamma^\mu}_{\nu\sigma}{T^\nu}_\mu\mathrm{d}x^\sigma$ for a basis ${T^a}_b$ of the $n\times n$-matrices $\mathfrak{gl}(n)$.

Comment: Highly useful and concise explanation utilizing the terminology of fiber bundles in the context of "standard" phrasing