Why Lorentz transformations instead of general linear transformations?
I am trying to understand why, in physics, we look specifically at Lorentz transformations, instead of the larger group of general linear transformations.
To fix the terminology: let spacetime be modeled as a four-dimensional Lorentzian manifold $(M, g)$. Then a Lorentz transformation at $p \in M$ is a linear map
$$\Lambda: T_pM \rightarrow T_pM $$
on the tangent space at $p$ such that $g_p(\Lambda X, \Lambda Y) = g_p(X, Y)$ for all $X, Y \in T_pM$. Given an orthonormal frame $(e_i)$ $(i=0,...3)$ at $p$, i.e., a basis of $T_pM$ with $g_p(e_i, e_j) = \eta_{ij} = $ diag$(-1, 1, 1, 1)_{ij}$, a Lorentz transformation maps it to another orthonormal frame at $p$.
Question: Obviously, geometric objects like tensors on $M$ and equations involving geometric objects are invariant under Lorentz transformations, for the trivial reason that we can choose and switch bases as we wish without affecting these objects (in contrast, their components with respect to a basis change, of course). However, geometric objects are even invariant under general linear transformations $GL(4, \mathbb{R})$ of bases, for the same reason. What is so special about Lorentz transformations then? What makes them stand out from the larger group of general linear transformations?
EDIT
An illustrative example: Maxwell equations on a curved (or, in particular, a flat) spacetime, written geometrically as dF = 0, d * F = J (* is the Hodge star), are invariant under GL(4, $\mathbb R$) transformations on tangent spaces, I think, not just under SO(1, 3), simply because they do not even make use of a basis. So preservation of equations of motion does not seem to single out Lorentz transformations.
END EDIT
A tentative thought: Lorentz transformations allow us to split spacetime locally into space and time in a physically meaningful way, in the following sense: given an orthonormal frame $(e_i)_{i=0,...,3}$ with $e_0$ tangent to an observer worldline (the "time" direction for this observer) and $\{e_1, e_2, e_3 \}$ spanning the "spatial" subspace of $T_pM$ for this observer, the spatial part of a photon 4-velocity has the same absolute value $c$, the speed of light, in any frame related to the given one by a Lorentz transformation. This is not the case for general linear transformations, without surprise: the decomposition of a 4-vector into a temporal and a spatial part is generally basis-dependent, if it makes sense at all in general non-orthonormal bases. This shows that in contrast to general linear transformations, Lorentz transformations preserve even some "non-geometric", generally basis-dependent quantities. But is that all that sets them apart?

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/356034/174766

Thanks @VincentThacker. But the question you mention asks about Lorentz transformations as coordinate transformations on a flat spacetime vs general coordinate transformations (diffeomorphisms). My questions is about Lorentz transformations acting on tangent spaces vs general linear transformations on tangent spaces.

Lorentz transformation preserve the line element

@Figaro They are the same thing.

You are asking why we want to treat the speed of light as observer-independent.  This is well explained in Einstein's 1905 paper, in terms of electrodynamic considerations.

A vector is a vector and has a length regardless of what coordinates you choose. So when computing lengths, the way the metric and vectors transform under GL_n cancel our. However, the equations of motion are different - they're preserved under SO(1,3) in that the equation literally doesn't change. This means if you act on a solution by SO(1,3), you get another solution. This is not true for GL as the equations of motion change. eg a solution to Maxwell with a moving charge can be understood by boosting to a frame where it's static, but only Lorentz fixes Maxwell's equations to get a new soln.

@ToyeshJayaswal, the Maxwell equations on a curved (or, in particular, a flat) spacetime, written geometrically as dF = 0, d * F = J (* is the Hodge star), are invariant under GL(4, R) transformations on tangent spaces, I think, not just under SO(1, 3), simply because they do not even make use of a basis. So preservation of equations of motion does not seem to single out Lorentz transformations.

@Figaro Yes, I think that's correct. What I'm trying to say however is the difference between passive and active transformation. If you passively transform (change coordinates), you haven't changed any objects, but the coordinates and equations change which compensate each other. But if you instead talk about the transformation as changing the particles/fields themselves, you aren't touching the equations since you aren't changing coordinates. Here, to get a new solution, you need to restrict to Lorentz.

General linear transformations correspond to coordinate transformations. Differential geometry is formulated in a way that geometric statements are independent of coordinates.
Poincaire transformations (translations + Lorentz transformations) are isometries of the Minkowski metric. Isometries are more than generic coordinate transformations; they are distance preserving transformations of a metric space.
From a physical point of view (stated in differential geometry language), isometries are important because they are associated with Killing vectors (or generally Killing tensors), which are associated with conserved quantities. So, the fact that energy and momentum are conserved in special relativity, for example, follows from the fact that these isometries exist on a Minkowski background. And, the fact that energy and momentum are not conserved in general relativity, follows from the fact that a general spacetime does not have corresponding time and space translation symmetries.
Stated in a different way, coordinate transformations are a local or gauge symmetry, and there is no conserved quantity associated with them. Poincaire transformations are a global symmetry of relativistic field theories in Minkowski space, and come with associated conserved quantities via Noether's theorem.

Thanks a lot. This seems to imply the following answer to my question (in bold face above): "In general relativity, Lorentz transformations don't have any special role, they do not stand out from the larger group of general linear transformations." Correct?

@Figaro The way I would say it is that Lorentz transformations are very important in Minkowski spacetime. In a general spacetime, global Lorentz transformations aren't even really defined, and don't play a special role. Of course, if the spacetime has any isometries, those are important. However, locally, any pseudo-Riemannian manifold will look like Minkowsi space, so local Lorentz transformations are important (they relate locally inertial frames, and also are crucial for the tetrad formalism).

I think a blanket statement like "In general relativity, Lorentz transformations don't have a special role" is too strong, because there are cases (Minkowski spacetime, local Lorentz transformations) where that isn't true, and it also does not acknowledge the role of isometries in general.

Because observations of physical reality show that space-time vectors, and the conjugate momentum-energy vector, transform as 4-vectors under Lorentz transformations.  This is just not true of a general linear transformation.
Think of time dilation and length contraction.  It is specifically the Lorentz transformation that correctly gives the distance and time between two events in one inertial frame based on the corresponding observation in another. A general linear transformation will not.

Space, time, velocity & Galilean relativity are intimately related in Newtonian physics. Any change in the definition of one of these notions will affect the others.
Einstein, by postulating the constancy of light velocity in any inertial frame, falsified Galilean relativity. This means how space, time & velocity are related change. These are now related by the Lorentz transformations. Further, the constancy of light in any inertial frame means we now have Lorentz relativity aka Lorentz symmetries. This is how Lorentz symmetry arose in physics although they had been discovered earlier as part of the symmetry group of EM.
