# Is there a way to visualise / understand intuitively the curvature in the $U(1)$ circle bundle responsible for the electromagnetic force?

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, curvature

In general relativity we have embedding diagrams of different slices of spacetimes. These can be quite helpful to understand the geometry of a given pseudo-Riemannian manifold (especially when the geodesics are drawn in). This way the curvature can quite literally be seen / understood intuitively.

Is there a similar way to visualise the curvature in the principal $U(1)$ fiber bundle (caused by a charged point particle fx.)?
If there is not, why?

Comment: Possible duplicate/worth checking: [Why does the analogy between electromagnetism and general relativity differ if you consider them as gauge theories or fiber bundles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/340371/226902) Potentially useful answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/490767/226902